# Adding to a JPanel which uses GroupLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, flowlayout, grouplayout

I would like to add components (`JButton` and `JSpinner`) to a `JPanel` which was created using Netbeans GUI builder. This panel uses `GroupLayout`, and I can't seem to use `add()` to add a component. Is there any way to either add something to a panel which has a `GroupLayout`, or change this panel to a `FlowLayout`?

Comment: *"This panel uses `GroupLayout`, and I can't seem to use `add()` to add a component."* Do you mean using the GUI builder, or at run-time?

Comment: I was trying to add it during runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option if you right-click the `JPanel` to change it to a `FlowLayout` (Set Layout). This fixed all the problems I was having.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely not an easy thing to do. It depends on where you want to add those components. I usually reserve an empty placeholder `JPanel` with GUI builder, and then add components to that panel, using whatever layout I want. However, this only works when you want to add components in one place. If they are scattered around the GUI, it may be not that easy.

Another options is to migrate to manual GUI creation, possibly using Netbeans-generated code as a starting point. But depending on how complex your GUI is, it may be a tedious work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I found out there is an option to set the layout of an auto-generated JPanel. So I just used that and it seems to work now.